# Require file somewhere in the directory node.js

Tags: node.js, require

I have a file that is required in many other files, that are on different folders, inside the `main` directory.

Is there a way to just require the filename without having to write the relative path, or the absolute path? Like `require('the_file')`. And without having to go to npm and install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder inside your main directory , put `the_file.js` inside and set the NODE_PATH variable to this folder.

Example :

Let's say you create a ./libs folder within your main directory, you can just use :

```
export NODE_PATH = /.../main/lib
```

after that, you can require any module inside this directory using just :

```
var thefile = require('the_file')
```

To not have to do that every time, you'd have to add the variable to your .bashrc (assuming you're running a Unix system).

Or you can set a global variable inside your app.js file and store the path of your 'the_file' in it like so :

```
global.rootPath = __dirname;
```

Then you can require from any of your files using :

```
var thefile = require(rootPath+'/the_file')
```

These are the most convenient methods for me, short of creating a private npm, but there are a few other alternatives that I discovered when looking up an answer to your question, have a look here : https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520